# Append same timestamp to multiple filenames

Tags: shell, filenames, date, timestamps, variable

I have several files that I ftp each hour.  The receiving system needs to have some sort of identifier that they came from the same batch, so I would like to append a timestamp to the filename.  That alone is fairly easy, but since I want each file to have the same timestamp (so it can serve as the batch identifier), I cannot figure out how to do this.

So, I have:

```
file1.txt
file2.txt
file3.txt
```

And I want to have:

```
file1_20141110184303.txt
file2_20141110184303.txt
file3_20141110184303.txt
```

Any use of the `date +%Y%m%d%H%M%S` after the first use will obviously result in a different values in seconds, so I would like to have the first timestamp appended to the remaining files.

Answer (score 5):

Just store the value of `date +%Y%m%d%H%M%S` in a variable:

```
x=$(date +%Y%m%d%H%M%S)
```

and later on

```
mv file1 file1_$x.txt
mv file2 file2_$x.txt
...
```

or in a loop for all `*.txt` files

```
for file in *.txt; do echo mv "$file" "${file%.txt}"_$x.txt; done
```

(remove `echo` if you are happy with what you see on the screen)